# Selenium : Element not visible Exception C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to "https://www.quora.com/" , It has login screen where I put my username and password , It always throws Element not visible, I have gone through all other answers on SO , none of them working.

I tried to click the element via Javascript and ScrollintoView , but no avail.

```
IWebElement uname = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", uname);
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", uname);
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", uname);
uname.SendKeys("myusername@uname.com");
```

None of them working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more login form (hidden) on page with `<input name="email">` element. You need to handle visible one. Try to use below code to locate required input field:

```
IWebElement uname = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='login']//input[@name='email']"));
```

Comment: I will check it , Once I get on to the system. thank you for your response.

Comment: It worked. I am learning to create xPath on my own. Want to suggest any resource?

Comment: You can also use a CSS selector here since XPath is not required. I find them easier to create/read, `div.login input[name='email']`. As for XPath resources, just about anything on MDN is good, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath. XPath is a complicated and powerful language but you'll find that you don't need a lot of what is available when you just use it in Selenium. Make yourself a cheatsheet as you learn common locators and you'll get the basics down pretty quickly.

Comment: @PankajKushwaha , [this one](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj-wJek5Y7dAhWJ2ywKHasqBu0QFjAAegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cheat-sheets.org%2Fsaved-copy%2FLocators_table_1_0_2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0pOEx8SWEHI6eYKu4-veXL) is quite useful

Answer (score 0):

To login to `https://www.quora.com/` you need to send a character sequence to the **Email** and **Password** field and you can use the following solution:

- *Email* field:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.text.header_login_text_box.ignore_interaction[name='email']")).SendKeys("myusername@uname.com");
  ```
- *Password* field:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.text.header_login_text_box.ignore_interaction[name='password']")).SendKeys("PankajKushwaha");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Find C# code for login as follows

```
[TestMethod]
    public void QuoraLogin()
    {
        ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30));
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.quora.com/");
        IWebElement email= wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='login']//input[@name='email']")));
        email.SendKeys("ABC@yahoo.com");
        IWebElement password = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='login']//input[@name='password']")));
        password.SendKeys("123");
        webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='login']//input[@value='Login']")).Click();
    }
```

Comment: I did not want the code. I wanted the reason why it is behaving so. I appreciate your efforts although.